# Online Storage Android App

Tags: android, web-services, google-cloud-endpoints, android-syncadapter

I am to build an android app that needs a central cloud storage (along with some server coding). My app is somewhat in the footsteps of 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.justyo

I mean i should be able to store a login and registration (possibly FB login in the future too). Then, i will also have to maintain and fetch users' 'friends' in the app along with a status (that can be changed any time by the friends).

I am not new with android dev. I also know ample amount of web development. However, i don't know the approach to this kind of an app that is to use some server side code and online db for android.
I have search a lot on the internet and have found a bunch of stuff, but i am just not getting the confidence as to which approach is what i need here.

- Is there something pre-built and given by Google themselves?
- Do i have to by a domain, deploy a hidden (UI-less) web service and access it through the android app?
- is there a free option out there by google?
- Is there a sample demonstration android app out there?

I don't need the code or anything. I am just confused; afraid of starting off in the wrong direction. Please answer so it is easy to understand.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I may have confused your question but have you looked at Google App Engine?

Comment: yes i came across a whole lot of things on google including this 'Google App Engine'. I'd just like to confirm if that is the thing i need here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the Google Cloud Platform, specifically App Engine. You can read the Docs [here.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs)
You dont't need to register a domain to use the platform. Yes, you will need to deploy a (not necessary UI-less) web service to the cloud, accessed from the Android client through endpoints. Additionally, the service is free up to certain limits.
Sample apps are available for deployment once you create a project from [here.](https://console.developers.google.com/)

Comment: Thank you. While looking up internet, i did come across Google App Engine too. I guess then that is exactly what i need here according to you.
So I am gonna go toward this.
Thanks a lot for guiding